# boot an installed linux virtually on mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, parallels

I'm using MacBookPro-Early-2015 OSX-10.10.5 .
I have an ubuntu installed in (hd0,gpt3) which boots correctly if I chose it in EFI boot option.

I want to boot it virtually from OSX using virtualbox or parallels or else programs.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking to if you can migrate your ubuntu install to virtual?

Comment: No, I just want to boot just like the feature of parallels "boot from bootcamp".

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is absolutely possible. Just install VirtualBox and create an Ubuntu virtual machine. Use the default settings (it knows what it's doing pretty well). Then start up the VM and when it asks you for the disk image, just choose the bootable Ubuntu drive you have.